# Ant -lib not working

Tags: ant

I'm trying to use the `-lib` option to specify a directory containing Ant tasks. But they're not loading. For example:

```
$ ant -lib /path/to/libraries
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/path/build.xml:3: taskdef class com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask cannot be found
```

The build file contains:

```
<project name="test">
  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />
</project>
```

This is failing on RHEL5, but the exact same thing works on several other operating systems that I've tried.

When I add the `--execdebug` flag, I get this:

```
exec "/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java" -classpath "/usr/share/java/ant.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxp_parser_impl.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-commons-apis.jar:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/lib/tools.jar" -Dant.home="/usr/share/ant" -Dant.library.dir="/usr/share/ant/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp "" "-lib" "lib"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Others seem to have the same problem on RHEL.

One workaround [suggested here](http://software.itags.org/apache/22462/) is to set your jar in the taskdef like so

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"
classpath="xmltask.jar"/>
```

Also [see this thread](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=118401858910262&w=2) which was a corrupt ant package